# boost::remove_if causing an error (Read-only variable is not assignable)

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

My method looks like this, getting an error during compilation "Read-only variable is not assignable" in vector.
What can be the problem?

```
int DownloadManager::RemoveDownload(const char *escapedTitle, const char *fileId)
{
    boost::remove_if(Core::defaultCore().GetSocketsQueue()->GetQueue(), [&](SocketConnection* socket) {
        if (strcmp(escapedTitle, socket->GetDownload()->escaped_title.c_str()) == 0 && strcmp(fileId, socket->GetDownload()->fileId.c_str()) == 0)
        {
            Core::defaultCore().GetDownloadQueue()->Remove(socket->GetDownload());

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Pasted just to show what GetQueue() above looks like.

```
std::vector<SocketConnection*> GetQueue()
{
    return this->sockets_queue;
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether it's related to the compile error, but you do realise you're modifying a temporary copy of `sockets_queue`? `GetQueue()` should probably return a reference or pointer.

Comment: Also, you might find `socket->GetDownload()->escaped_title == escapedTitle` easier to read than the equivalent `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return reference from `GetQueue`, since now you are trying to remove from temporary variable, that is not allowed, because `remove_if` first parameter is expected to be reference, there is no conversion from temporary-variable to reference.

Comment: Changing it to `std::vector<SocketConnection*>& GetQueue()` did the trick. Thanks.